# Normal USB Stick from Bootable USB

Tags: usb, bootable-media

I have made my usb bootable but I don't know how to make it work as a normal pendrive?
if there is any specific process exist for that so tell me....

Comment: I'm assuming that, in the pendrive Venn diagram, "bootable" resides entirely inside "normal".

Comment: Do you mean that, if it is left in a USB slot, you don't want it to get recognized as bootable when booting up?

Answer (score 24):

1. Run CMD as Administrator
2. Type `DISKPART`
3. `list disk`
4. `select disk 1` (if your usb drive mine was 1)
5. `clean`
6. `create partition primary`
7. `active`
8. Choose a format:

   - FAT32 is the standard for USBs: `format fs=fat32 quick`
   - NTFS is more modern, but isn't as widely supported: `format fs=ntfs quick`
9. `assign`
10. `exit`
11. `exit`

Comment: Ankhbayar Bayarsaikhan is right but simply you can format it with windows.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this situation many times. 
Try this tool

[Partition Wizard](http://download.cnet.com/MiniTool-Partition-Wizard-Home-Edition/3000-2094_4-10962200.html)

Install the tool. 
Remove the existing partition of the flash drive. 
Add new Partition. 
Format the new partition

Now your pendrive will work as before.